# Reuse subquery results in multiple SELECT in Oracle (Can't create table)

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

I have multiple SELECT queries using same subset of data. I  would like to reuse it so no repeated subqueries or WITH clause.  However, I can't CREATE TABLE or VIEW because of insufficient privileges. So is there a workaround?

I'm using TOAD Oracle.

For example,

```
WITH LOCAL_RESULTS
    AS (SELECT a, b, c, d...
          FROM SURVEY )
SELECT A, B
FROM LOCAL_RESULTS
where condition=1


WITH LOCAL_RESULTS
    AS (SELECT a, b, c, d...
          FROM SURVEY )
SELECT A, C
FROM LOCAL_RESULTS
where condition=2


WITH LOCAL_RESULTS
    AS (SELECT a, b, c, d...
          FROM SURVEY )
SELECT B, D, A... 
FROM LOCAL_RESULTS
where condition=3
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

A union query might work.

```
with local_results as
(subquery goes here)

select a, b, c, 1 condition
from local_results
where whatever
union 
select a, b, null c, 2 condition
from local_results
etc
```

Comment: Thanks Dan but I would like to avoid using UNION because the 3 results pattern is very different. The select statements here are very simplified.